# heroku and sails app | crashes and timeouts

Tags: heroku, sails.js

I have a very basic sails app up and running locally. When I deploy to Heroku, I cannot get a response from the app and then eventually get "Application Error". I sometimes receive "No data received".

**heroku logs**

```
2015-08-30T22:06:50.949475+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v22 created by me

2015-08-30T22:08:57.324207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boo
t timeout" method=GET path="/" host=www.ninjalist.io request_id=8e21f6eb-1a59-4e
31-9c40-00aab002d0f1 fwd="118.61.238.166" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2015-08-30T22:08:52.058851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down

2015-08-30T22:11:55.735176+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=ninjalist.herokuapp.com request_id=314047d1-97d8-
40ea-8596-4b21978eb581 fwd="108.61.228.166" dyno= connect= service= status=503 b
```

**heroku logs --source app**

```
2015-08-30T21:40:42.149449+00:00 app[web.1]: > firstApp@0.0.1 start /app
2015-08-30T21:40:42.149452+00:00 app[web.1]: > sails lift --prod
2015-08-30T21:40:42.149453+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-30T21:40:42.149430+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-30T21:40:42.873435+00:00 app[web.1]: ←[90mStarting app...←[39m
2015-08-30T21:40:42.871270+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-30T21:40:42.873742+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-30T21:40:44.441658+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemorySt
ore is not
2015-08-30T21:40:44.441664+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environme
nt, as it will leak
2015-08-30T21:40:44.441666+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a s
ingle process.
2015-08-30T21:41:04.326177+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: The hook `grunt` is taking t
oo long to load.
2015-08-30T21:41:04.326187+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.
js:119:15)
2015-08-30T21:41:04.326183+00:00 app[web.1]: Make sure it is triggering its `ini
tialize()` callback, or else set `sails.config.grunt._hookTimeout to a higher va
lue (currently 20000)
2015-08-30T21:41:04.326185+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tooLong [as _onTimeout] (/ap
p/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:92:21)
2015-08-30T21:41:04.587989+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-30T21:41:04.641592+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bi
n/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-08-30T21:41:04.641839+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v0.12.7
2015-08-30T21:41:04.668957+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
2015-08-30T21:41:04.669159+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-08-30T21:41:04.669368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! firstApp@0.0.1 start: `sai
ls lift --prod`
2015-08-30T21:41:04.669504+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2015-08-30T21:41:04.669672+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2015-08-30T21:41:04.669827+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the firstApp@0.0
.1 start script 'sails lift --prod'.
2015-08-30T21:41:04.670024+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob
lem with the firstApp package,
2015-08-30T21:41:04.670133+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-08-30T21:41:04.670267+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2015-08-30T21:41:04.670427+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     sails lift --prod
2015-08-30T21:41:04.675558+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via
:
2015-08-30T21:41:04.676317+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls firstApp
2015-08-30T21:41:04.697584+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-30T21:41:04.676320+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2015-08-30T21:41:04.701882+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-08-30T21:41:04.640986+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-
```

**Procfile**:

```
web: npm start
```

**package.json / scripts**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "node debug app.js",
    "start": "sails lift --prod"
  }
```

**config/env/production**:

```
module.exports = {

  models: {
    connection: 'mongoDbProd'
  },

  port: 80,

  log: {
     level: "silent"
  }

};
```

Any direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a specialized buildpack for Heroku that runs the Grunt tasks on deployment, and then turn off Grunt in Sails for the production environment.  It's a bit more work, but it can become necessary because Heroku has its own timeout which can be tripped by Grunt taking too long to crunch your assets.

We've had success with [heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt](https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt).  You can follow the instructions to install it on your Heroku app, then copy the task definition in your `tasks/register/prod.js` to include `heroku:production` task, e.g.:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.registerTask('prod', [
    'compileAssets',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'cssmin',
    'sails-linker:prodJs',
    'sails-linker:prodStyles',
    'sails-linker:devTpl',
    'sails-linker:prodJsJade',
    'sails-linker:prodStylesJade',
    'sails-linker:devTplJade'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('heroku:production', [
    'compileAssets',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'cssmin',
    'sails-linker:prodJs',
    'sails-linker:prodStyles',
    'sails-linker:devTpl',
    'sails-linker:prodJsJade',
    'sails-linker:prodStylesJade',
    'sails-linker:devTplJade'
  ]);

};
```

Then finally in your `app.js` file, replace

```
sails.lift(rc('sails'));
```

with:

```
var config = rc('sails');
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.hooks = config.hooks || {};
  config.hooks.grunt = false;
}
// Start server
sails.lift(config);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this as well.

Comment: Didn't work for me :/
remote: >> Uglifying source .tmp/public/concat/production.js failed.
remote: Warning: Uglification failed.
remote: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>).
remote: Line 1575 in .tmp/public/concat/production.js
remote:  Use --force to continue.
remote:
remote: Aborted due to warnings.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...

Comment: @Suisse sounds like the uglification itself is failing, which is a different issue from what the OP faced.  I'd check that it works locally.  A common cause of uglification failing is the use of ES6 syntax without first transpiling with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: @sgress454 thx it was because of the arrow function (lambda functions) this solved the problem: npm install git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#harmony --save

Answer (score 3):

From: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2691

Creating a file config/locals.js with the following resolved the issue for me:

```
module.exports = {
   hookTimeout: 30000, // 30 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting hookTimeout, make sure you have

```
  migrate: 'alter'
```

set in config/models.js

Answer (score 0):

Adding the official Heroku Node.js buildpack worked for me: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

In Heroku CLI:

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
```

Then:

```
git push heroku master
```

Everything should build successfully, and your app should run just fine in Heroku.