# grunt task is not executing after deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I have a sails application which I created using the steps in the sailscasts and it works correctly in development.

But when I push it to heroku, the grunt task does not execute and the css and javascript is not linked.

I have registered the following task in the Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.registerTask('heroku:production', 'build');
```

My node version is 0.12.7 and sails version is 0.11.0

This might be related to

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1872
but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here that Sails has hardcoded tasks to be called. If you take a look into `lib/hooks/grunt/index.js` you will see `initialize` method that calls your tasks.

```
initialize: function (cb) {
  sails.log.verbose('Loading app Gruntfile...');

  if(sails.config.environment === 'production') {
    return this.runTask('prod', cb);
  }

  this.runTask('default', cb);
}
```

So you must have two tasks with `prod` and `default` names.

If I'm not mistaken, Heroku runs your application in a production mode, so you must have your `prod` task (even if you modify something, you must modify `prod` task), but not the `heroku:production`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to prevent grunt from minifying in production and use the default css and js the way that it works for development ? I'm guessing I have to comment out something in one of the grunt tasks but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: As I say, all what you need to do is modify `prod` task. Take a look at `tasks/register` and `tasks/config` folder and you'll find Grunt tasks that you can modify.

Comment: I removed the call to cssmin in tasks/register/prod.js but now I get no css when I run sails lift --prod Is there another way to stop the minification step so I can debug why my styles are not rendering correctly in production?

Comment: What about `sails-linker` tasks ? Just removing some task without understanding what's going on doesn't resolve this. Did you work with Grunt before? You have a bundle of tasks that minifies assets, copies them and links with EJS templates. If you don't minify CSS then you don't need to link prod assets but dev assets. So disable `sails-linker` prod tasks.

Comment: @Das: @EugeneObrezkov is right in that your `heroku:production` task won't get run just because you added it--not sure where you got that from, but it's something we usually along with a special buildpack for deploying Sails apps to production on Heroku.  If you follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301779/heroku-and-sails-app-crashes-and-timeouts/32320884#32320884) it should get you all the way there.